# Cant successfully make simple call to HERE Platform

Tags: postman, here-api

I'm using postman to send queries to [here Platform](https://www.here.com/). I need to get the fuel prices at gas stations around Europe. I'm using Postman: This is the query string Postman generates:

```
https://fuel-v2.cc.api.here.com/fuel/stations.json?prox=39.41807152612494, -0.5043256138070775&fueltype=1
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

I'm using the API key I generated on the website. I could make some successful but useless queries. Is it about pricing? After I pay they will provide me the data ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated under the documentation for this API, you likely don't have access.

> Note: Please note that the Fuel Prices service is only available to
> automotive OEMs for in-vehicle applications.

Refer to: https://developer.here.com/documentation/fuel-prices/dev_guide/topics/overview.html